# Are there daemons in Gehennom?

Tags: halacha, gehinnom, sheidim-demons

If one suffers wrath in Gehennom, who carries it out?

Is it the souls of the dead, is it strange creatures, daemons?

If Gehennom is a real place (on earth) why do we not see daemons and suffering there?

Comment: I don't think anyone says Gehennom is on earth...

Comment: Do you mean [shedim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shedim)?

Comment: There are gemaros that give locations to the entrance to gehenom. There's a sefer written about the nature of gehenom but I can't recall the name.

Comment: Eruvin 14a - וְאָמַר רַבִּי יִרְמְיָה (בַּר) אֶלְעָזָר: שְׁלֹשָׁה פְּתָחִים יֵשׁ לַגֵּיהִנָּם, אֶחָד בַּמִּדְבָּר וְאֶחָד בַּיָּם וְאֶחָד בִּירוּשָׁלַיִם. בַּמִּדְבָּר, דִּכְתִיב: ״וַיֵּרְדוּ הֵם וְכׇל אֲשֶׁר לָהֶם חַיִּים שְׁאוֹלָה״. And Rabbi Yirmeya ben Elazar also said: There are three entrances to Gehenna, one in the wilderness, one in the sea, and one in Jerusalem. There is one entrance in the wilderness, as it is written with regard to Korah and his company: “And they, and all that appertained to them,

Comment: Many sources use the term Malachei Chavala, which can be translated as demons. However, there are many interpretations on this subject

Comment: The Christian concept of demons does not really fit in Judaism. There are destructive angels created by sins of people. There are also *shedim*, but they are closer to the non-Jewish term "spirits" than demons.

Answer (score 1):

While it is far too long to quote here, and I'm not sure if there is an English translation, the [Reishis Chochmah in Shaar Hayir'ah chapter 13](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14032&st=&pgnum=72&hilite=) quotes Maseches Gehennom and discusses the topic extensively. (I know the link I provided puts it in chapter 12, but my copy at home has it squarely in chapter 13 and as a rule I rely on newer printings because they often have mistakes corrected. And it looks like it's a mistake in this edition מיניה וביה as well, as per [page 70](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14032&st=&pgnum=70).) There are a number of levels of Gehennom which accomplish different objectives in different ways, including through various destructive angels ("malachei chavalah," as @Chatzkel points out). The Reishis Chochmah then proceeds to discuss the potential need for a gilgul, if the damage is too extensive. I do warn you, this read is rather arcane and abstruse.

Regarding your question about whether there is a physical place called Gehennom, the gemara in [Eruvin 19a](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.19a.18) asks this and concludes that it is a valley (גיא "gei") which is as deep as Gehennom - in other words, just a metaphor, rather than a physical location of Gehennom. The entrances discussed there can be understood as locations where individuals were sent to Gehennom rather than a physical manifestation of Gehennom on earth. And all of this makes sense from a logical perspective, as it is a place of cleansing for the Neshamah once it is separated from the body - thus it is an entirely spiritual experience.

Comment: I've heard from my grandparents, who grew up in Yerushalaim of old, that there is a custom of the Chevra Kadisha to run past a specific place near Har Hazeisim if they are taking a body there as they have a mesora that this is the place of the entrance to Gehennom. (They added that the custom started when a body they were carrying disappeared as they walked past). I've heard about this custom recently again, but i can't find any sources for this.

Comment: @Chatzkel Is that the valley right next to Har Tziyon? I believe I've heard the same, about that area.

Comment: Im not sure exactly, but sounds right